# Reload a route that has state based on query params using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route that sets state in the constructor based on the query parameters. Since React Router doesn't have the option to route based on query parameters, even if the query parameters change, React Router treats it as the same route.

For example, React Router treats `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/?page=2` as the same route. If I redirect from the second page to the first page, the constructor doesn't run again. However, I need the constructor to run again to reset the state.

Is there a way to force React Router to reload a route?

Here's a solution that works, but it's very hacky.

```
function redirect(path) {
  browserHistory.push('/fake-path');
  setTimeout(_ => {
    browserHistory.replace(path);
  }, 0);
}

...


<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={AppRoute}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomeRoute}/>
    ...
    <Route path="fake-path" component={_ => null}/>
  </Route>
</Router>;
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `componentWillReceiveProps` of your component to check the query params changes.

```
// AppRoute.js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (this.props.location.query.page !== nextProps.location.query.page) {
      // handle query parameter change here
   }
}
```