# Is there a non-hacky way to force React to destroy and re-construct an element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Long story short, I would like React to create a completely new element rather than reuse an existing element. This is so it runs the constructor again.

By default, React tries to reuse as much as possible. A hacky workaround is to add a `key` property to an element. For example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      forceReloadCounter: 0,
    };
  }

  _forceReload() {
    this.setState({forceReloadCounter: this.state.forceReloadCounter + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildElement key={this.state.forceReloadCounter}/>
    );
  }
}
```

If `_forceReload` runs, it changes `ChildElement`'s `key`, so React destroys the old instance of `ChildElement` and constructs a new one. However, this solution is obviously very hacky. It would be confusing to anyone else reading the code. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What's the reason/use case for why you'd want to destroy and reconstruct an element?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe simply removing it from DOM would work? Like a conditional which would render it only if some condition is true.

`render() { return condition ? <Element /> : null }`

Comment: The `componentWillMount` pulls data from sources other than the `props`. It would be confusing to reset all the data and refetch the data (if the element is reused). I think it's cleaner to just re-construct the element and call `componentWillMount` again.

Comment: @VincasStonys I still need to render the element, but I'd like to create a new instance of it.

Comment: I don't imagine a use case. Maybe you could explain the problem you're solving, so maybe we can identify if there is a better way of achieving it? It sounds like you're trying to go against what is react's intention. It isn't really meant to recreate object, but by providing optimizations using it's virtual dom, actually prevent rerenders and reinitializations as much as possible. Really the only correct ways to "restart" a component is to use it's lifecycle methods and  props/state.

Comment: Yes I'm going against React's intention, because it's not always the best choice. Here's additional context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168672/reload-a-route-that-has-state-based-on-query-params-using-react-router/42168909#42168909

Comment: As others say, it would be the parent's responsibility to unmount and remount the child, though as you can see from your linked example, react router won't do that if the query params change. that's exactly what `componentWillReceiveProps` is for

Comment: If you upgrade to react router 4, which is beta now, your problem is trivially solved

Comment: The answer provided there is a correct way of doing it though, albeit it is a bit awkward. As azium has said, React Router v4 tries to solve this problem.

Comment: this feels like an xy problem because you're asking how to do a hacky thing in a non hacky way

Comment: *"It would be confusing to reset all the data and refetch the data (if the element is reused). I think it's cleaner to just re-construct the element and call componentWillMount again"* So destroying and refetching is less confusing than resetting and refetching?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, because the child element won't have to worry about route changes. It becomes solely the parent element's concern.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class that uses my hacky solution in a cleaner way.

```
class RecreateChildOnPropsChange extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._forceRecreateCounter = 0;
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    assert(nextProps.children, 'Every props object should have childrens.');

    let props = this.props;
    if (props === nextProps) {
      return true;
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(props);
    let nextKeys = Object.keys(nextProps);

    if (keys.length !== nextKeys.length) {
      return false;
    }

    for (let key of keys) {
      if (key !== 'children' && (!nextProps.hasOwnProperty(key) || props[key] !== nextProps[key])) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  render() {
    this._forceRecreateCounter++;

    return React.cloneElement(
      React.Children.only(this.props.children),
      {key: this._forceRecreateCounter}
    );
  }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
<RecreateChildOnPropsChange startingPage={page}>
  <Newsfeed startingPage={page}/>
</RecreateChildOnPropsChange>
```

If any property of `RecreateChildOnPropsChange` changes, it destroys and recreates its child element.